# How to use the t() function in a class component with a constructor?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next

Using [i18next](https://react.i18next.com) with react, I would like to use the `t()` function in class components, but most of the time, I also need to initialize the state, so I would like to have a constructor as well.

Following the [documentation here](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc#use-typescript-with-class-components) I get this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {WithTranslation, withTranslation} from "react-i18next";

interface ExampleProps extends WithTranslation {

}

interface ExampleState {

}

class Example extends React.Component<ExampleProps, ExampleState> {
    render() {
        const t = this.props.t;
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{t('Test')}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(Example);
```

This works fine, no problem here. Until I add a constructor:

```js
    constructor(props: ExampleProps, context: any) {
        super(props, context);
    }
```

`withTranslation` won't work with this:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Example' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<WithTranslationProps>'.   Type 'typeof Example' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<WithTranslationProps, any>'.     Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.       Type 'WithTranslationProps' is missing the following properties from type 'WithTranslation<"translation">': t, tReady
```

[image]

If I use `interface ExampleProps extends WithTranslationProps {}` the type incompatibility disappears, but I can't access the `t` function, because the `WithTranslationProps` only has a `i18n?` nullable type and I can't add anything to the `ExampleProps`, because I get `Property 'newProperty' is missing in type 'WithTranslationProps' but required in type 'ExampleProps'.`

`const t1 = this.props.i18n?.t;` results in `TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'` when trying to call `t('Test')`.

`const t2 = this.props.t;` does not exists.

**One solution, If I just initialize the state directly in the class, like:**

```js
class Example extends React.Component<ExampleProps, ExampleState> {
    state = {
      // set state here
    }

    render() {
```

Although I would still like to know if there is a way to use a constructor here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t need to implement a constructor for your React component.

But, wait a minute, what is the `context` you passed to `constructor`?

you only need to pass `props` as the parameter of the `constructor`.

> constructor(props)

Comment: True. I auto generated the constructor with the IDE, hence the two params. If I only pass the props everything works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In react constructor and super methods receive either 0 parameters or 1 (if it's 1, then they should be props), as per [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

In your render you can just do

```
render () {
   const { t } = this.props;

   return (
            <div>
                <p>{t('Test')}</p>
            </div>
        );
}
```

This deconstruction of the components props makes your code more readable, if you need more variables from props, just add a comma and the name of the variable, and it will be usable inside that function.

Other than that your code seems fine